# how often do bootstrap variables change

Tags: variables, bootstrap-4, versioning

Switching from `"bootstrap": "~4.0.0-beta.2"` to `"bootstrap": "^4.0.0"` added new variables in the `_variables.scss`. Boostrap classnames only change when there is a major version upgrade (AFAIK), but does the same apply to  `_variables.scss` too?

It would change how we share the `_variables.scss` accross our application.

Comment: The variable names shouldn't change as Bootstrap 4 is now in "real" release. The variables are there for a good reason: Your CSS shouldn't break when you upgrade. (not counting major versions of course)

Comment: Of course new variables can be added. Those *shouldn't* break your CSS.

Comment: @Klooven if you put this as answer, I'd accept it. Also give a hint how to implement it with scss (include the original _variables.scss from the boostrap folder an the ones you overwrite in a separate "_variables.scss" where only the changes ones are added without "!default" at the end)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Does variable names change between releases?

The variable names **shouldn't change** as Bootstrap 4 is now in "real" release (out of beta).

The variables are there for a good reason: **Your CSS shouldn't break when you upgrade.** (*not counting major versions of course*).

Of course new variables can be added, as those shouldn't break your CSS.

If you are in any way unsure before upgrading, you can always check the [changelogs](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases). Those should tell about any breaking changes.

#### Using variables in SCSS

When you have set up your build tools, and created your SCSS file (let's say `custom.scss`), you can import Bootstrap and override any variable you want (*you'll find them in `_variables.scss` in the Bootstrap source code*):

```
//Your variable overrides

//Let us change the primary color which is set in the primary variable
$primary: #ce40c5;

//In this case we are importing everything
//Here we are using NodeJS with NPM, so your files should be here
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Some things to note:

- If you aren't using NodeJS, then just make sure that the import path directs to the `bootstrap.scss` file (don't put `.scss` in the import)
- If you have checked the source code of Bootstrap 4, you may have seen `!default` after every variable. **Don't include** that in your override. It just tells Sass that the variable can be replaced

There's a bunch of good information about this in the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/), so feel free to check there if you are missing anything (*or ask*).